# How to get value of selected dropdown when the nearest text field validates

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown and associated textbox in each row. Depending on the value selected in the dropdown, I have to validate the textbox value. I need to get the dropdown value of each row.

For example, the dropdown id will be `select id="i-re-type-0"`, `select id="i-re-type-1"` and so on.

```js
console.log('Value of nearest : ' + $(element).closest('.row .enabled-options').find('.ref-type-select').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span5 enabled-options">
    <select id="i-re-type-0" class="span4 ref-type-select" name="i-re-type">
      <option data-maxchars="500" value="">Select reference...</option>
      <option data-type="text" data-validation="required" value="AES">AES</option>
      <option data-type="text" data-validation="required" value="FRT">FRT</option>
      <option data-type="text" data-validation="required" value="VTY">VTY</option>
    </select>
    <div class="hide disabled-options"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="span11">
    <input id="i-ref-val-0" class="validateRefe required" type="text" title="Reference" value="" name="i.ref[***]" style="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You were close `$(element).closest('.row').find('.enabled-options .ref-type-select').val()`

Comment: Getting an empty string

Comment: What's the `element`?

Comment: `var options = [];
$(element).closest('.row').find('.enabled-options .ref-type-select').find('option').each(function(){
    options.push(this.value);  }); console.log(options);`

You got empty string, because the 'Select reference...' option value is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $( ".ref-type-select" ).change(function() {
      var textValue = $(this).closest('.row').find(".validateRefe").val();
      var drpValue = $(this).val();
    
      $(this).closest('.row').find(".validateRefe").val(drpValue )
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span5 enabled-options">
    <select id="i-re-type-0" class="span4 ref-type-select" name="i-re-type">
      <option data-maxchars="500" value="">Select reference...</option>
      <option data-type="text" data-validation="required" value="AES">AES</option>
      <option data-type="text" data-validation="required" value="FRT">FRT</option>
      <option data-type="text" data-validation="required" value="VTY">VTY</option>
    </select>
    <div class="hide disabled-options"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="span11">
    <input id="i-ref-val-0" class="validateRefe required" type="text" title="Reference" value="" name="i.ref[***]" style="">
  </div>
</div>
```